# How to change default/current schema in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preety basic question from my end that I unfortunately could not find an answer to.
In my database I have 2 schemas with their respective tables. Schema X and schema Y.
While I can simply pull the data easily from schema X with

`SELECT * FROM employees`

I cannot do the same with schema Y, forcing me to use

`SELECT * FROM SchemaY.customers`

My question is, how can I change the current or default schema from X to Y so I can query the tables without the `SchemaY.` in the table names begining.

Kindest

Marcin

ps: I utilize Postgres and play around in DataGrip.

Comment: Use the `search_path`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

```
set search_path = schemay, public;
```

You can also do that for your user permanently:

```
alter user current_user 
  set search_path = schemay, public;
```